# Create Sample with Specific Distribution

Tags: sas, distribution, sample

In SAS, what is the best way to take a sample from a population while controlling its characteristics? Is it possible to take a sample while specifying a min/max/mean/std dev? It's easy enough to filter something down so that you end up with the necessary averages for whatever characteristics you're looking for, but I need the distributions to look a specific way too. Any thoughts on the best way to approach this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity,why do you want to do that? One usually takes a sample to estimate the population characteristics (mean,std) and so tries to find a way to extract a sample with the same characteristics of the population, if the sample has its own distribution, what use is it to you? Or do you want to generate from scratch a variable with wanted characteristic for some kind of simulation?

Comment: It'd be hard to explain what I actually want to do with this, but maybe this made up example will help. Say you have a dataset that is every stock from 1960-2000, a few characteristics about it and it's monthly performance. Now, in 2001 you're evaluating some mutual funds that hold many different stocks that didn't exist previously. The idea is to look at the distribution of those characteristics in the mutual fund and try to build a similar grouping of stocks from the dataset you had to look at performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROC SURVEYSELECT is the standard procedure for sampling data.  There are many methods and options available, although I don't know if you can get to exactly your requirements with it.  Check out the online guide and other papers relating to this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

you can put in strata what ever variable(s) you want to be representative in your sample .
I think you can simulate for example the same stocks value distribution for instance